# Docker for Mac - run X11 applications without an active internet connection

Tags: docker, x11

I'm using Docker for Mac to run some data analysis software. I followed a number of different tutorials in order to use X11 applications from the containers. Invariably, these tutorials use the host's IP address to define the DISPLAY variable, e.g.:

`$ read junk ip junk <<< "$(ifconfig en0 | grep inet\ )"
$ docker run -ti -e DISPLAY=$i:0 (...)`

This usually works well. But what if I *don't* have an active internet connection? The method above obviously doesn't work.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You could try using the [loopback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback#Virtual_loopback_interface) address and see if that works. You shouldn't need a proper internet connection to talk to a container running on the same host.

Comment: By loopback you need 127.0.0.1? It doesn't work :(